# Writing Script in PHP to test a website load time

Tags: php

Writing Script in PHP to test a website load time.

I am trying to write a script that the user can enter a website and the script will return the load time of the index page with images for the site.  does anyone have a sample code

Comment: keep in mind that the load time will be the combination of: (1) loading the page itself - you can test this, (2) parsing the page - your parse time will almost certainly will be different from that of a full browser; (3) retrieving additional pieces (.js, .css, images, etc.) - again, you can test this; (4) - parsing all those individual pieces - again, your time will be different from any browser; (5) laying out the page - not sure how you can test this; and (6) executing any "onload" handlers - again, not sure how you'd test this.  Thus, you can only get an approximation.

Comment: Any reason you want to do this yourself instead of using existing tools, such as Chrome's development console that does.. exactly that, broken down in fine details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very broad question.

Doing this in PHP is probably a non-starter.  Web browsers download resources like images, external scripts, css files, etc, in parallel.  Getting PHP to do likewise would involve a bunch of ugly process-wrangling, and the results probably wouldn't necessarily relate to browser behavior anyway.

Consider using existing programs that do this sort of thing - various extensions for popular browsers are a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already know the solution to track the loading time without the images (so only server-side, not client-side)?

At the beginning of the script:

```php
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
```

At the end of the script:

```php
$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
$processTime = "Processing time: ". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds";
echo "<!-- ".$processTime." -->";
```

If you want to track even the clients loading time (eg resources etc) you have to consider a javascript approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the **[microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)** function to calculate the time difference in microseconds which passes between the point in which you initiate the page request and the point when the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XHProf which is described in a nice [article](http://phpadvent.org/2010/profiling-with-xhgui-by-paul-reinheimer) by Paul Reinheimer or you can use [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

But for a first impression FireBug's Network-Monitor and just calculating timestamp-differences with PHP might be an option.